# jQuery validator addMethod syntax

Tags: jquery

I can't find anything in the internets about which version of this would be more correct.

```
  if (value == '00/00/0000'){
    return false;
    return /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/.test(value);
  }
```

OR this

```
  if (value == '00/00/0000'){
    return false;
    return (/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/).test(value);
  }
```

Also what is really the difference and what would be more correct?

Comment: Neither, you can't have two `return` statements ^^

Comment: `()` are not necessary.

Comment: what should I do then, can you suggest something for me?

Answer (score 0):

The () is not necessary.

```
if (value === '00/00/0000'){
    return false;
} else {
    return /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/.test(value);
}
```